# Laravel 5.8. How use variable of .env file in webpack.mix.js

Tags: laravel, webpack, environment-variables

I did the following in .env file:
APP_ENV=production
MIX_APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"

In webpack.mix.js file:
const APP_ENV = process.env.MIX_APP_ENV;

Using the if else operator, I checked that nothing was assigned to the APP_ENV variable.
I need to do the following - depending on the environment, compile sass and js files into a specific folder.

I'm trying to do the following, but nothing works:

```
const APP_ENV = process.env.MIX_APP_ENV;

if (APP_ENV == 'dev' || APP_ENV == 'production') {
    mix
        .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
        .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css')
        .version();
} else {
    mix
        .setPublicPath('public/build')
        .setResourceRoot('/build/')
        .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
        .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css')
        .version();
}
```

Comment: Your `.env` file is not loaded into your environment, rather the `dotenv` PHP library used by Laravel looks for the `.env` file and makes the values available through the `env` helper at runtime -- allowing environment variables to override `.env` specified values. This means that outside of PHP you'd need to use an equivalent library, e.g: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack or https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: `dotenv` is a dependency of `laravel-mix`

Answer (score 3):

There was no need to create an intermediate variable MIX_APP_ENV in the .env file.
The following code is working:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const env = process.env.APP_ENV;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use it like that because you are in `JS` file and JS does not have to access it. 
You can install with `npm` the dotenv `npm install dotenv --save` and use it like this : 'require('dotenv').load();' inside your mix file and now you can do it :

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
       // code
    }
```

Comment: But I need to read the data from the .env file, not from the package.json

Comment: Where does the variable NODE_ENV come from?

Comment: Sure, installing the package `dotenv ` you will read it. Automatically the package read from root. `NODE_ENV` is a static variable

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old quesion, but the simplest fix (to make your code work) is to change...

> I did the following in .env file: APP_ENV=production MIX_APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"

..to..

> APP_ENV=production
>   MIX_APP_ENV=production

(your webpack.mix.js is not going to be able to convert "${APP_ENV}" into "production")